# Redirect link error in Winter '18 with lightning theme

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, winter18

I have a Visualforce page with following code to redirect page **abcd** 
when click link:

```
<apex:outputLink value="/apex/abcd?sfdc.tabName={!tabName}&state=group"
    >abcd</apex:outputLink>
```

In lightning theme version Summer'17 it working well but when update to `Winter '18`, it's not working with following error message:

> Apex page **abcd** does not exist.

When I check inspect element on browser I see url of 2 version is different:

- Summer '17:

  ```
  <a href="/one/one.app#/alohaRedirecthttps://account-geolocation-dev-ed--c.ap2.visual.force.com/apex/abcd?sfdc.tabName=...&amp;state=...&amp;isdtp=p1">abcd</a>`
  ```
- Winter '18:

  ```
  <a href="javascript:srcUp('%2Fapex%2Fabcd%3Fsfdc.tabName%3D01r0k0000008jRJ%26state%3D...%26isdtp%3Dp1');">abcd</a>
  ```

How can fix problem? Please share some thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

Using relative URL does not work in all scenarios. Better would be to use [$Page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_page.htm) global variable as it dynamically generates appropriate Page URL:

Try replacing your code with following-

```
<apex:outputLink value="{!$Page.abcd} + '?sfdc.tabName=' + tabName + '&state=group'"
    >abcd</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: Or use 'lightning:formattedUrl' base component